# upload photo for a html project

Tags: html, css

I want to code a simple website just with HTML and CSS . I did it with notepad on my PC.

When I added a background photo to my `#header` element, it isn't working. I've tried to replace the name and used from online editors.

I can't find my error.

I have a folder with `style.css` and `index.html` and a folder for the photos on my website.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  height: 100vW;
  background-image: url(images/Al-Hakawati.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chehel Behesht</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <section id="header">
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226848/discussion-on-question-by-jasmine-upload-photo-for-a-html-project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the css file format. If you look at the image you showed, your css file format is **TextDocument**. Ideally, the css file format should be **CSS-Document**.

And this confirms the error you are getting:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND style.css:1
```

To fix this error, open your `style.css` stylesheet in a notepad. Next, select **File - Save As...** And finally, specify the file extension `.css`. Like this [picture](https://ibb.co/N3RwsTx).